# better way of caching webservice responses

Tags: php, performance, caching, memcached

My application heavily uses webservices and doesn't use database atall. there is a webservice layer which gets data from database and sends it to php UI. so the phpUI doesn't directly interact with the databases. I want to improve the performance of this application what is a better approach to improve the performance?
should I use memcached and cache control headers  or is there any other way to implement the caching to improve the performance? I want a way to reduce my Http requests to webservices

Comment: Why don't you use a framework that does the caching for you?

Comment: @Ic2817 What kind of framework im using Zend right now and you think using Memcached will actually work for me in this scenario?

Comment: @David which server are you talking about webserver or the database server?

Comment: @David not sure i have to talk to infrastructure team and find out

Answer (score 3):

since you use the term "webservice" I assume that you are using HTTP as the transport layer.  If you are using RESTful architecture for your webservices, all you need is a standard http caching proxy in-between your app and the services.

Comment: what do u mean by standard http caching proxy? like using cacahe control headers?

Comment: I was thinking of using memcached to cache the web service response isnt it the right approach?

Comment: I wouldn't know without a detailed understanding of your architecture and requirements

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a webserver like nginx or lighttpd if possible. They are a magnitude faster and easier to configure.

Comment: I cannot use any kind of servers i have to stick with what ever they use.